# Запятая перед союзом «и» и после него

Tags: запятые, союзы, и

**1.** *Звуки постепенно замирали, **и** чем дальше уходили мы от дома, тем глуше и мертвее становилось вокруг.*
Союз *и* присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение.

3апятая ставится и перед союзом *и*, и после него, если он соединяет два простых предложения (причем после придаточной части не следует вторая часть двойного союза):
**2.** *Крепкий был человек Гуляев, **и**, когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера.*

После союза *и* во втором предложении идет такое предложение: "когда он вернулся на Урал, за ним тянулась блестящая слава миллионера".

Я не пойму, почему в первом предложении *и* присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение, а во втором — простое? Соответственно: запятая после союза *и* ставится и не ставится.

Answer (score 3):

В первом примере, который Вы привели, содержится вторая часть составного союза - чем...тем. Запятая по общим правилам ставится перед союзом *и*. Во втором примере содержится два союза: сочинительный и **одинарный** подчинительный союз. В этом случае при встрече сочинительного и подчинительного союза запятая ставится между сочинительным и подчинительном союзом.

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь Д. Э.